# Extract a tar file to specific root dir regardless of the root dir inside the tar

Tags: tar

I'm trying to extract a tar file where the contents of its dirs may change from time to time. I'd like to be able to extract the tar file regardless of what the root dir is. For example:

tar path and filename = /home/user/archive1.tar

If I run tar zxvf /home/user/archive1.tar -C /home/user then it's all extracted to /home/user/archive1 including any subdirs. The problem is that another tar file may extract to a different dir like /home/user/archive070320

What I need is to always extract to /home/user/myowndir and any files and subdirs that are in the tar file go to this dir. So even though inside the tar file it has a root dir of archive1 or archive0730320 or whatever, I'd like to replace that target rootdir with my own static root dir such as 'myowndir'

Also, it would really help if this could be done on one line and preferrably work on any Linux as well as AIX.

Comment: i wonder strip leading `'/'` is default behavior except you ran with `-P` but try `--strip-components 2` together with (existing) targetdir like `-C ~/myowndir/` or use a sed expression `tar --transform 's,home/user\(.*\),myowndir\1,'` https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html